# VBA Change text on checkbox

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word

I am working on a macro in MS-Word.
I have a checkbox called WeaponsChecked and a text field called WeaponsText.
Onclick, I want to add text to the text field.
This is my newbie attempt. Of course it does not compile.
I'm getting a message error: "end if without block if"
:) Where do I go from here?

```
Sub WeaponsMacro()

If WeaponsChecked.Checked = True Then WeaponsText.Text = "Time"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I can do that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do either:

```
If WeaponsChecked.Checked = True Then WeaponsText.Text = "Time"
```

or

```
If WeaponsChecked.Checked = True Then 
    WeaponsText.Text = "Time"
End If
```

Comment: So? I had a layout issue? That's why I got "end if without block if"?
I copied-pasted your second example and I get "Object required" as an error? :D (Totally guessing at this.)

Comment: Yes, you had a syntax issue. Now that it's solved, you have another issue. Sounds like you either don't have a `CheckBox` named "WeaponsChecked" or a `TextBox` named "Weapons.Text", or both.

Comment: Hmm. Who knows. Now MSWord is crashing.

Comment: I'm using word2000. Maybe it's too fragile?
I have a checkbox named WeaponsChecked and a textbox named WeaponsText.
I have opened it using word 2013, resaved as a docm file and I get the same error.
I have selected the name of my macro on "Run Macro on Entry" for the checkbox.

Comment: Then how do I name an object?

Comment: if the name under bookmark is not the name of the textbox, how do I name the textbox?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the question. I'd try an internet search on something like "Microsoft Word name an object". If that doesn't help, I suggest starting a new question here on SO. If possible show a screenshot and be sure to describe what you've already done and what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user1022466 You can use `ActiveDocument.FormFields("myField").Result` to access your fields.

Comment: Are FormFields for the legacy controls? What about the newer ContentControls?